# JS проблема с отображением

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем Привет. Есть некий скрипт который, в зависимости от полученного значения, вставляет в ячейку таблицы знак *true* или *false* (Знак зеленого цвета птичка-true, знак красного цвета false x-черточка)
Ячеек 100 штук Они находятся в таблице. Реализовал это так:

```
<td><img src="" style="width:16px;height: 16px;"></img></td>
```

*Это пустая ячейка квадрат размером в 16px;
А это мой Скрипт:

```
//МОЙ СКРИПТ 
var timeStatus = setInterval(function() {
  var fisrtValue = 10;
  var secondValue = 8;

  var fisrtValue1 = 10;
  var secondValue1 = 8;

  var fisrtValue2 = 10;
  var secondValue2 = 8;

  checkStatus(firstValue, secondValue);
  checkStatus(firstValue1, secondValue1);
  checkStatus(firstValue2, secondValue2);
  //и таких штук 50 ...
}, 1 * 500);

function checkStatus(a, b) {
  var c = a - b
  if (c >= 0 && c < 2) {
    //console.log('Online');
    $('td').eq(3).children().attr('src', 'image/online.png');
  } else {
    //console.log('offline')
    $('td').eq(3).children().attr('src', 'image/offline.png');
  }
}
```

Все работает интервал через каждые пол секунд работает проверяет и вставляет в зависимости от значения картинку.

ПРОБЛЕМА:

1. когда много  таких переменных ,Тоесть функцию вызываю раз 50 для
   каждой ячейки таблицы а их 50 .То скрипт не успевает тоесть
   ,некоторые значения которые должны быть вставлены они не корректно
   отрабатываются он начинает мигать )
2. Иногда вообще все ячейки становятся пустыми на секунд 2-3 потом
   снова в них запихивается картинка. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Обновляйте только то, что изменилось. Да и виртуальный DOM - дело нужное.

Comment: @Other ваш ответ мне ничем не помог

Comment: Поэтому это комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: :)Можно по подробнее про то как обновлять только то что изменилось

Comment: сделайте картинку свою на css лучше фоновым изображением ячейки и дергайте классы, куда удобнее будет, имхо. Вы написали что ячеек 100 штук, а картинка меняется всегда в третьей.

Comment: @teran вы не так поняли 3 индекс это номер колонки с img

Comment: @elik да, похоже на то. Дабы избежать проблем. когда вдруг колонка станет не третьей, а четвертой, лучше пометьте их всех `<td class="status">`, а иконки меняйте добавляя к ним еще класс-маркер `class="status success"` или `class="status failed"` это упростит ваш код

Comment: в любом случае логика мне не совсем ясна. друг за другом функция меняет иконки во всех строках. Один черт увидите вы только последнюю версию выставленных значков полученную в результате последнего вызова функции checkStatus. То что происходит в середине приведет к различным артефактам отображения и вообще не имеет смысла. В чем суть то?

Comment: я бы понял, если бы вы написали запуск `checkStatus` с разными параметрами раз в 500мс (на что намекает `setInterval`), но у вас то они идут одна за другой.

Comment: @teran  воьщето данные берутся из  колонок таболиц )это время поситителя и проходит через определенный фильтер ) просто код выложить немогу попвтался воссоздать прототип действия но вы правы данные изменяются

Comment: @elik что то не совсем зачем Вам setInterval?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick в интервале у меня берутся данные для переменных.Посто в этом примере я поставил строго данные но в коде данные в интервале меняются

Comment: Нет, я к тому, зачем это делать в интервале? можно было бы обойтись например callback функциями. Почему именно интервал?

Comment: Я к чему веду, может Вам не setInterval надо. Объясните, пожалуйста, 
1 как происходит бизнес процесс
2 почему решили пользоваться setInterval

Comment: например вы говорите, что  в интервале у меня берутся данные для переменных. Почему они разные каждый раз почему 500мс выбрали для интервала? Как эти данные формируются?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick ОК понел ,значит есть некая таблица в ней данные времени  я беру данные этого времени и сравниваю их с временем сервера .и ставлю им фотки онлайн или офлайн .А интервал потому что переодически проверяю

Comment: ага, то есть как я понял серверное время вы аяксом тянете? И на момент вызова интервала у Вас уже есть это время?

Comment: хммм а вот это классный вывод пойду протестирую